# How to embed a C# Image in a web response

Tags: c#, image

I have created something like this: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/485182/Create-a-local-server-in-Csharp

But the tutorial only shows how to send a string. But when I try to modify the code by adding an `img src`, it won't show up. This is what I have done so far:

```
private void sendData(int total, DataGridView dgv, Image v)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => ResponseThread(total, dgv,v));
    t.Start();
}

private void ResponseThread(int t, DataGridView dgv, Image u)
{
    String table="";
    HttpListenerContext context = _httpListener.GetContext();
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
        table += "<tr><td>" + dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "</td><td>" + dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "</td><td>" +
            dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "</td><td>" + dgv.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "</td><td>" + dgv.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString() +
            "</td><td>" + dgv.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString() + "</td></tr>";

    byte[] _responseArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
        "<html>" +
        "<head>" +
        "<title>Hello</title>" +
        "</head>" +
        "<body>" +
        "<h1>Total: " + t +
        "<table style=\"width:100%\"> <tr><b><th>No</th><th>Centroid X</th><th>Centroid Y</th><th>Orientation</th><th>Area</th><th>Area (mm)</th></b></tr>"+
        table+"</table>"+
        "<img src="+u+"></img>"+
        "<p><i>Last Update: " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "  "+DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()+
        "</i></p>" +
        "</h1></body></html>");
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(_responseArray, 0, _responseArray.Length);
    context.Response.KeepAlive = true;
    context.Response.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add u (Image variable) to a string, .NET framework will call u.ToString() and add the output to the string, so the result string will be `<img src="Image"</img>`

If you need to make it correct:

1. Either pass the URL of the image, if its on a common place.
2. Base64 encode the image and keep it inline (within the html).
   Example:

`<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />`

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but you need to handle the bytes of the `Image` separately.  Once the browser gets your response data, it needs to be able to understand how to read the image.  `<img src="+u+"></img>` is not sufficient.

Most of the time, browsers will get a URL in the `src` attribute, and the image file is downloaded and displayed as-is.  In your case, the image bytes need to be embedded in the response, but in a safe way so they can be transmitted and unpacked.  Thankfully, this is possible via base-64 embedding.  The data should take the form `data:image/png;base64,<base-64-encode-bytes>` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images) for more details.  **IMPORTANT** - if you're not using PNG files, you'll need to change `image/png` in that string appropriately.

Now to get the bytes into the format - converting the `Image` instance into a string using `ToString()` is not sufficient, however with a few extra steps it's possible.  Use `MemoryStream` and `Convert` like so - this will give you the long string of bytes you can embed in your response.  Again, if you don't want to use PNG, you'll need to change your `Save` call appropriately.

```
string base64 = "";
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    u.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
}
```

**Important** side note - if these images are very big, then embedding might not be a good idea for performance reasons.  But for small images this should be OK.